# como resolver: young object promotion failed Allocation failed?

Tags: npm

He estado programando normalmente, pero de pronto he empezado a tener este problema y no se que puede ser, alguna idea?

Node Version: v14.15.0

NPM Version: 6.14.8

OS: Window 11 Pro

```
[9756:0000026DE58939A0]    42794 ms: Mark-sweep (reduce) 4091.4 (4104.6) -> 4091.2 (4105.4) MB, 2137.0 / 0.1 ms  (average mu = 0.077, current mu = 0.001) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed
[9756:0000026DE58939A0]    46472 ms: Mark-sweep (reduce) 4092.2 (4102.4) -> 4092.0 (4103.9) MB, 3677.2 / 0.1 ms  (average mu = 0.030, current mu = 0.000) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed


<--- JS stacktrace --->

FATAL ERROR: MarkCompactCollector: young object promotion failed Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: 00007FF638911DDF napi_wrap+109135
 2: 00007FF6388B6D06 v8::internal::OrderedHashTable<v8::internal::OrderedHashSet,1>::NumberOfElementsOffset+33350
 3: 00007FF6388B7AD6 node::OnFatalError+294
 4: 00007FF6391864CE v8::Isolate::ReportExternalAllocationLimitReached+94
 5: 00007FF63916B31D v8::SharedArrayBuffer::Externalize+781
 6: 00007FF63901574C v8::internal::Heap::EphemeronKeyWriteBarrierFromCode+1516
 7: 00007FF6390002EB v8::internal::NativeContextInferrer::Infer+59339
 8: 00007FF638FE571F v8::internal::MarkingWorklists::SwitchToContextSlow+57503
 9: 00007FF638FF947B v8::internal::NativeContextInferrer::Infer+31067
10: 00007FF638FF050D v8::internal::MarkCompactCollector::EnsureSweepingCompleted+6269
11: 00007FF638FF86CE v8::internal::NativeContextInferrer::Infer+27566
12: 00007FF638FFC64B v8::internal::NativeContextInferrer::Infer+43819
13: 00007FF639005E82 v8::internal::ItemParallelJob::Task::RunInternal+18
14: 00007FF639005E03 v8::internal::ItemParallelJob::Run+643
15: 00007FF638FD9583 v8::internal::MarkingWorklists::SwitchToContextSlow+7939
16: 00007FF638FF09CC v8::internal::MarkCompactCollector::EnsureSweepingCompleted+7484
17: 00007FF638FEF204 v8::internal::MarkCompactCollector::EnsureSweepingCompleted+1396
18: 00007FF638FECD18 v8::internal::MarkingWorklists::SwitchToContextSlow+87704
19: 00007FF63901B4F1 v8::internal::Heap::LeftTrimFixedArray+929
20: 00007FF63901D5D5 v8::internal::Heap::PageFlagsAreConsistent+789
21: 00007FF6390127F1 v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage+2033
22: 00007FF6390109F5 v8::internal::Heap::AllocateExternalBackingStore+1365
23: 00007FF639030F17 v8::internal::Factory::NewFillerObject+183
24: 00007FF638D5E731 v8::internal::interpreter::JumpTableTargetOffsets::iterator::operator=+1409
25: 00007FF63920F01D v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+463949
26: 00007FF63920FECD v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+467709
27: 000001FDCDB98C0D
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 134
npm ERR! ultima@11.0.1 start: `ng serve`
npm ERR! Exit status 134
```

he probado tambien utilizando:

--max_old_space_size=8192

pero el error continua...

Comment: Tienes un leak y se está agotando la memoria. Sin más detalles, te queda asignar aún más memoria o revisar si hay problemas con las dependencias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gracias a quienquiera que trató de ayudar. El problema era en mi código, tenia un error. Un error bastante estupido por cierto:

```
[(ngModel)]="percentage / 100"
```

Por supuesto no se puede asignar una operación a ngModel...

Comment: Buen hallazgo! Es el tipo de cosas que pasa en el mundo de node. Recuerda aceptar tu propia respuesta (por ahí mañana tendrás la opción)